# How to extract a number (integer or double) and text from a string in C# with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a small unit conversion in C# and I am countering a problem. I looked in to a few examples on the internet but I failed to apply

```
Example text input:
12m 
12 m
12.4m
.5m
12.m
```

I would like to `string num` and `string unit`

```
new Regex(@"([\d.])([a-zA-Z- -/]+)");
```

This only gives me result if the input has `int`like `12m` not `12.m` or `12.4m...`

I could work around to include `.` in the input text but now the input has to have `.` , also happens with the decimal part.

```
new Regex(@"([\d.][.][\d.])([a-zA-Z- -/]+)");
```

Although I could do multiple possible cases to handle different input formats, the code looks bad. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: FYI tip: If you struggle with understanding how your regex really works, there are plenty of online regexers that can help you greatly in testing and visualizing regular expressions and how they match a given string; for example: http://regexstorm.net/tester, https://www.debuggex.com/ or https://regexr.com/

Comment: If you use one of those online regex tools, you will quickly notice that your original regex `([\d.])([a-zA-Z- -/]+)` does not completely match `12m`, contrary to what you seem to believe (the first group does not match `12`, but only `2`).

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/AfotDQ/1, try `(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)\s*([a-z]+)`

Comment: Thank you all for suggestion - solution from @WiktorStribiżew works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)\s*([a-z]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AfotDQ/1)

**Details**

- `(` - start of the Capturing group 1:

  - `\d*\.?\d+` - 0+ digits, an optional `.`, 1+ digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+\.?\d*` - 1+ digits, an optional `.`, 0+ digits
- `)` - end of Capturing group 1
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([a-z]+)` - Capturing group 2: one or more lowercase letters.

Comment: couldnt you just have done (\d*\.?\d*) instead of (\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*) ?

Comment: @HeribertoLugo No, because `\d*\.?\d*` matches an empty string and `(\d*\.?\d*)\s*([a-z]+)` might [yield "funny" output](https://ideone.com/aFiHAe).